# Facebook Like Button Not working: Error unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to implement the Facebook Like Button but its not working. In short I can press the like button and it will say that I liked this. But nothing comes up on my profile and when I post a comment, nothing happens. It is also creating a javascript error: "Error unterminated string literal".

Here's [the page I have it implemented on](http://epk.devinshosting.com/?page=videos&command=viewvideo&option=rick-ross---huslin). Everything seems to work, except nothing comes up in the user's profile. It throws this JavaScript error:

> Error unterminated string literal:
>   static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zP/p/r/rfgCJM79Mlq.js

And I have the social meta tags inserted too:

```
enter code here 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="162971323718605"/> 
<meta property="fb:admins" content="40509315"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="KeyStar PR"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="music"/> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://epk.devinshosting.com"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="KeyStar PR"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://epk.devinshosting.com/apps/PVElectronicPressKit/images/default_album.jpg"/>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No errors in Fx 3.6.10 on Mac - try clearing your cache

Comment: Very strange, it worked when I fixed browser. Went from FireFox to Safari. Thanks for giving me that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta properties aren't the fault (and they're more usefull for the share API rather than the like button).

Looks like it's working to me tough, most likely you have/had a broken string (like *'this isn't right'* instead of *'this isn\'t right'*).

I noticed you use the iFrame version, why not switch to the FBML version? Might make life easier for you... What browser issues the error? I tried with Mozzila and FireBug didn't spit any error, even more it posted on my wall after I clicked "Like".

Comment: I don't know what it was. I switched from using FireFox to Safari. Now that this atleast works, I plan to implement it with xFBML.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not related to any actual code but the browser. Problem solved.